# ¿Mantener los valores de un ArrayList aunque cierre el programa? (Java) (SIN GUARDARLO EN UNA BASE DE DATOS)

Tags: java, array, variables, arraylist

Actualmente no estoy muy experimentado con Java y quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de mantener los valores de un Arraylist o un arreglo aunque cierre el programa SIN usar una base de datos.

**Ejemplo simple**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main(){
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList <Integer> lista = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    lista.add(3);
    lista.set(0,lista.get(0)+1);
    System.out.println(lista1.get(0));
}
```

**Lo que quiero conseguir**

Cada vez que cierre el programa, la lista en la posición 0 se mantenga el valor antes de que finalice su ejecución.
**Ejemplo**

*Primera salida de información al ejecutar el programa*

4

*Segunda salida de información al ejecutar el programa*

5

*Tercera salida de información al ejecutar el programa*

6

Y así sucesivamente...
Quizás el ejemplo y/o el código no sea el mejor ejemplo, pero espero haberme explicado bien...
PD: El arraylist igual puede cambiar a un arreglo para lo que ando buscando.

Comment: Puedes crear un archivo de properties de java para almacenar variables como arrays como por ejemplo el indice por el que vas del array [Link de creación y utilización properties](http://programacion.jias.es/2011/10/creacion-de-ficheros-properties-con-java/) [Link de modificación de properties](http://www.w3api.com/wiki/Java:Properties.setProperty())

Comment: Lo que te hará pensar un poco es que el sistema de archivos es de por sí una base de datos. Entiendo que no deseas usar un motor de base de datos tradicional, que, a menos que sea uno basado en memoria, igual guarda los valores en el sistema de archivos. Al final de cuentas siempre estarás persistiendo los datos en el sistema de archivos (ya sea local o en la nube). Saludos

Comment: Existen varias formas, lo más fácil es guardar en un archivo los valores, cada línea es un valor del array.
También existe la manera de guardar en un archivo un Objeto Java, por lo tanto cuándo lees el archivo recuperas el objeto tal cual lo guardaste.
Por último puedes hacer uso de archivos de texto plano diseñados para guardar datos tales cómo xml o json, e incluso csv aunque este último es menos recomendable.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes guardar tu variable en un archivo. Puedes hacer algo como esto, no estoy seguro por que usas una lista en tu ejemplo ya que solo manejas un elemento, pero puedes hacer esto.
Utilizando [Java NIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) es relativamente sencillo.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Integer n = 3;
        Path stored = Path.of("./stored.txt");

        //si el archivo existe entonces leemos el archivo
        if (stored.toFile().exists()) {
            String content = Files.readString(stored);
            n = Integer.valueOf(content);
        }
        n = n + 1;

        //guardamos el archivo
        Files.writeString(stored, String.valueOf(n));
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Cada vez que ejecutes el programa imprimira lo que se guardo en el archivo + 1.

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar archivos : texto plano, XML, JSON, etc si no quieres usar una BD.

```
{
  "ejecuciones": [
    {
      "salida": "1",
      "valor": "4"
    },
    {
      "salida": "2",
      "valor": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero , como mantendría esos valores aunque cierre la aplicación? , revisar [answer], saludos.